# CSS Transition with truncated multiline text

Tags: html, css, whitespace, transition

I've got following code [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/oq4mgbue/2/):

As you can see, there is a truncated multiline text which expands if its clicked. I've also added a transition for max-height for a smooth shift.

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: green;
}

.lbl-toggle {
  max-height: 30px;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.truncate {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle {
  max-height: 350px;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle>span {
  text-overflow: initial;
  overflow: initial;
  white-space: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="collapsible" class="flexbox lbl-toggle">
    <span class="truncate">Text here is very very long that it might get truncate if this box get resized too small. Text here is very very long that it might get truncate if this box get resized too small</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

However, the whitespace-property is making problems in interaction with max-height and the transition. Only the initial transition is working, afterwards its not more working. I think if I'm applying then truncation and `white-space: nowrap` is set my max-height isn't applied anymore and the transition breaks.

My only idea is that I need to delay when white-space property is applied with JS. However, i don't want to use JS. Is there another solution?

Comment: Is there a precise reason why you don't want to use JS? Note that in here it works for the expanding transition after the first time, but it's just that you need to wait a full second after minimizing the label (max-height **1s** ease-in-out;). It's normal if the minimizing is not transitioned because `white-space: nowrap` will probably affect the `height` and not `max-height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly the inconsistency of `max-height` in/out transitions is a well-known issue in CSS - [this article](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/#article-header-id-1) explains the issue fairly well, and provides a couple of alternatives that may be of use.

Comment: Thanks for this article. It points out really well the differnt use cases. Sadly, it is not possible for me to use a translation without JS.

Comment: No worries @Theiaz, best of luck in any case!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to get rid of the ellipsis and set your collapsed max-height to your line height, it's the ellipsis and line-height that forces you to use `white-space: nowrap;` which is the guilty for the transition not to work properly.
**NOTE** that the `max-height` property should be applied to the span too (`.truncate`) if you really want to control this property with this class (in my code I applied to all inner elements)

As you correctly guessed, the other solution would be to use JS, which I don't really understand why you want to avoid. The script is not complex and you wouldn't need a fake checkbox.

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: green;
}

.lbl-toggle/*, .lbl-toggle > **/ {
  max-height: 18px;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle/*, .toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle > **/ {
  max-height: 350px;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle > .truncate {
  overflow: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="collapsible" class="flexbox lbl-toggle">
    <span class="truncate">Text here is very very long that it might get truncate if this box get resized too small. Text here is very very long that it might get truncate if this box get resized too small</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

**JS solution:**

```js
var collapsibles = document.getElementsByClassName('lbl-toggle'),
    i, l = collapsibles.length;

for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
  collapsibles[i].onclick = function(){
    var self = this;
    if(self.classList.contains('expanded')){
      self.classList.remove('expanded');
      setTimeout(function(){
        //the if is a safety in case of many rapid clicks
        if(!self.classList.contains('expanded')){
          self.classList.add('nowrap');
        }
      }, 1000);
    }else{
      self.classList.add('expanded');
      self.classList.remove('nowrap');
    }
  };
}
```

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: green;
}

.lbl-toggle {
  max-height: 30px;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.nowrap .truncate{
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.truncate {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.expanded {
  max-height: 350px;
}

.expanded > .truncate {
  text-overflow: initial;
  overflow: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="flexbox lbl-toggle nowrap">
    <span class="truncate">Text here is very very long that it might get truncate if this box get resized too small. Text here is very very long that it might get truncate if this box get resized too small</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to use JS to keep the overload of the application as small as possible. Furthermore, this transition was even more a addon and a personal question for me. However, thanks for this example!